# Binding code data to XAML pivot listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I´m struggling with data binding here for **Windows Phone 7.1**. I've got a `DataLoader` class with an `OnservableCollection` of `ItemList` (custom class) as an attribute. Therefore, each pivot item has its own list of items. In this `DataLoader`, I load the data from a JSON a JSON. So far, so good.

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemList> PivotItem { get; set; }
```

Here, I store five `ItemList`, one for each pivot header with his corresponding list of items.

But my problem is that I want to bind this data to the XAML with a `ListBox` within each PivotItem.

```
<phone:Pivot Title="iMetrópolis" Loaded="Pivot_Loaded">
        <!--Elemento Pivot 1-->
        <phone:PivotItem 
            x:Uid="PivotItem1"
            Header="Todo" Margin="14,10,10,18">

            <ListBox x:Name="FirstListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                        // I want to add textboxes binding my data
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </phone:PivotItem>
        .
        .
        .
```

Thanks for the replies!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i think you need to do , an example for databinding

```
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Height="auto" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PON}"  />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PIN}" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

and a class for it

```
   public class ListObject
    {
        public string PON { get; set; }
        public string PIN { get; set; }
    }
```

and binding real data from json

```
     dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsondata);

     var questions = new List<ListObject>();
      foreach (var abc in json["jsonarray"])
                {
     var listOfItems = new ListObject();
listOfItems.PON= abc.object1;
listOfItems.PIN= abc.object2;
 questions.Add(listOfQuestions);

}

  listBox1.ItemsSource = questions;
```

i hope it helps reply for any comments

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But you use `questions` as `ItemsSource` for the `ListBox`, however PON and PIN take their values from another source different than the content inside `questions` objects(?). Well, I have (for example a list of titles (strings) and I want to use it as my `ItemsSource`, but I want to show each string in the PON `TextBox`.

Comment: Hi mate! I've already understood the whole Binding matter. Your reply was really helpful indeed!!